# How to use the collect function in Groovy to find all objects by the name of a field?

Tags: groovy, findall, collect

I know the question is confusing, let me explain. I have an object like this

```json
scmStage: {
"execute": true,
"parallel": true,
"integrationPoints": [
    {
        "method": "checkout",
        "checkout": {
            "credentials": {
                "type": "credentialsId",
                "id": "bitB1"
            },
            "type": "GIT",
            "url": "...",
            "branch": "feature",
            "component": true
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "scm",
        "scm": {
            "credentials": {
                "type": "credentialsId",
                "id": "bitB1"
            },
            "type": "GIT",
            "url": "...",
            "branch": "master"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "scm",
        "scm": {
            "credentials": {
                "type": "credentialsId",
                "id": "bitB1"
            },
            "type": "GIT",
            "url": "...",
            "branch": "dev"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I need to check each of the integration points, until I find the one with the property

```
"component": true
```

In this case, it's the first one. If the integration points had all the same method (lets say `METHOD_SCM`), I would do something like this:

```
integrationPointComponent = (Map) (((List<Map>) scmStage.integrationPoints)?.findAll {
      it.method == Constants.METHOD_SCM
  })?.collect {
      (Map) it.scm
  }?.findAll {
      it.component
  }?.size() == 1
```

And I would have my integration point with the component property, but, the reality is that the integration points can have three different names (`METHOD_SCM`, `METHOD_CHECKOUT` and `METHOD_GIT`)

And I would need to do something like this

```
integrationPointComponent = (Map) (((List<Map>) scmStage.integrationPoints)?.findAll {
    (it.method == Constants.METHOD_SCM || it.method == Constants.METHOD_CHECKOUT || it.method == Constants.METHOD_GIT)
    })?.collect {
        (Map) it.scm  <-------PROBLEM
    }?.findAll {
        it.component
    }?.size() == 1
```

I need for each method to write its name in the collect function depending on the method if its `METHOD_SCM`, then it should be `it.scm`, if its METHOD_CHECKOUT then it should be `it.checkout`, and similar with git.

Is there any way to write it up in one go, instead of writing 3 different cases for each one, something like using the method property as a field within the collection, something like this:

```
?.collect {
    (Map) it.[it.method]   or ${it.method} or  something else...need help
}?.findAll {
    it.component
}?.size() == 1
```

Or another way of asking this question is, what would be the best way of getting the integration point with the component property?

Edit 1: @daggett
I tried the first variant as @dagget suggested, like this:

```
(((List<Map>) scmStage.integrationPoints)?.find{
it.method in ['checkout', 'git', 'scm'] && it[it.method]?.component==true })
```

And the first part: `it.method in ['checkout', 'git', 'scm']` throws an error:

```
'ArrayList<String>' cannot contain 'Object'
```

I solved it by converting the it.method to string, like this:

```
(String)it.method in ['checkout','scm', 'git']
```

But one issue remains in the second part: `it[it.method]?.component==true`

That is the following:
`No candidates found for method call it[it.method]?.component`

But, the funny part is, it's working!
Thanks man, have an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def scmStage = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(''' {
"execute": true,
"parallel": true,
"integrationPoints": [
    {
        "method": "scm",
        "scm": {
            "credentials": {
                "type": "credentialsId",
                "id": "scm-bitbucket"
            },
            "type": "GIT",
            "url": "...",
            "branch": "master"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "checkout",
        "checkout": {
            "credentials": {
                "type": "credentialsId",
                "id": "scm-bitbucket"
            },
            "type": "GIT",
            "url": "...",
            "branch": "feature",
            "component": true
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "scm",
        "scm": {
            "credentials": {
                "type": "credentialsId",
                "id": "scm-bitbucket"
            },
            "type": "GIT",
            "url": "...",
            "branch": "dev"
        }
    }
]
}''')


def p = scmStage.integrationPoints.find{ it.method in ['checkout'] && it[it.method]?.component==true }
assert p
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just needed to convert it to tstring, as per my edit1 in the question, and it somehow worked even if it has an error msg.